# Is that how 'Long' works (in Java)?

Tags: java

Look at this Java code:

```
class PerformanceTest2{

    public static void main(String args[]){

        Long sum = 0L;

        for(int i=0;i<Integer.MAX_VALUE;i++)
            sum += i;

        System.out.println("Sum = " + sum);
    }
}
```

It is observed that it takes longer for this code since sum is 'Long' & not 'long'. So in every iteration what happens is:

```
sum = new Long(sum.longValue() + i); (for sum+=i;)
```

So, a new object is created every time. Doesn't Java support C++ like feature of returning a reference so that we could've written (possibly):

```
sum.longValue() += i;
```

possibly not having to create sum object every time around the loop? Am I right?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well, it doesn't call the constructor. It uses:

```
for (int i = 0; i < Integer.MAX_VALUE; i++)
{
   long tmp = sum.longValue(); // Unboxing
   tmp += i;
   sum = Long.valueOf(tmp); // Boxing
}
```

The wrapper objects are *deliberately* immutable - they could easily have been designed to be mutable, but immutability is often a very useful feature. If you want to write your own mutable wrapper type, you're very welcome to - at which point you could have code such as:

```
LongWrapper sum = new LongWrapper(0L);
for (int i = 0; i < Integer.MAX_VALUE; i++)
{
    sum.add(i);
}
System.out.println("Sum = " + sum);
```

Or possibly:

```
LongWrapper sum = new LongWrapper(0L);
for (int i = 0;i < Integer.MAX_VALUE; i++)
{
    sum.setValue(sum.getValue() + i);
}
System.out.println("Sum = " + sum);
```

Comment: the program with sum being 'long' ran in 1.660s while this one (sum being 'Long') took 9.367s. So can this be the reason? And doesn't Java create sum every time around the loop?

Comment: @AmitL: Yes, the boxing is almost certainly the reason. The `Long.valueOf` method will be called on each iteration, but that doesn't *necessarily* create a new value. For example, values between -128 and 127 inclusive are guaranteed to be cached.

Comment: The example code will very quickly move beyond the range of `{-128, 127}`.  I think it's safe to say that on nearly every iteration the constructor will be called (by way of `Long.valueOf()`).  At least on the initial pass through the loop.  And probably also on subsequent passes, as it seems unlikely that Java would cache anywhere near `Integer.MAX_VALUE` instances of `Long`.

Comment: I'm actually a bit surprised that the JIT doesn't simplify the code accordingly (should be doable). Probably because that's exactly the "wrong way" around. You usually use primitives and let the compiler autobox it to an object if necessary.

Comment: @Voo: Don't forget that any optimization the JIT compiler has to be aware of takes time while it's doing the JIT compilation. It makes more sense for that time to be spent optimizing *sensible* code than working out how foolish code can be made to look non-foolish.

Answer (score 1):

I invite you to take a look at the testcases I've set up here:

http://ideone.com/Hvbs1

Your code is slow not because you are mixing `long` and `int` types, but because you are using `Long` instead of `long`.  The `Long` type is a proper object, and immutable to boot, so every time you assign a new value to your variable, a new object is being constructed (a possible exception is if a cached object already exists for the new value).  This is an expensive operation (relatively speaking).

As you will see from the example code, changing the loop to add a `long` instead of an `int` does not make it run any faster.  The way to speed it up is to change the first variable to a `long` instead of a `Long`.

Answer (score 0):

Java has no C++ like references. Also, the built-in wrapper classes for primitive types are deliberately made immutable. One of the reasons for this decision is, that the run-time may then cache the wrapper instances for particular values, and avoid having to create a new object (this requires, that you call `valueOf` instead of allocating a new object via `new`; the compiler does this for boxing).

Answer (score 0):

> So, a new object is created every time. Doesn't Java support C++ like
>   feature of returning a reference so that we could've written
>   (possibly): ...

If you use `Long` you are explicitly requesting wrapper type from Java. And the convention for wrapper types is: they are immutable. And immutability (as constness in C++) requires that no modifiable internals must be given to the outside. But a C++ like reference would exactly do that. (Let's skip the const reference part because that also wouldn't help you in C++.)

> possibly not having to create sum object every time around the loop? Am I right?

Theoretically yes, but if you want that behaviour, why don't you use not a plain `long` right from the start?

Comment: so in the given program, is sum created every time around the loop? Hope not.

Comment: Of course. You asked for `Long` - you`l get it. It's that simple.
If you don't want that, use `long` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Others have already explained why `Long` takes longer then `long and how using`Long.valueOf` may be slightly faster.

Please, **don't let this be a reason for not using Long**. In all likelihood your overall system throughput time will *not* be affected by it.

If there are tight loops where this affects performance then use the primitive `long` there, a hand-rolled wrapper as Jon describes or [MutableLong](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.4/org/apache/commons/lang/mutable/MutableLong.html) from apache commons.

Comment: Actually I don't see any reason to use "long" in that situation. Thanks to autoboxing we get the object if necessary anyhow and don't have the performance overhead.

Comment: If I understand you right you are saying you can just use for example a `Set<Long>` and `put` a `long` in it and autoboxing will take care of the conversion. Correct, just know that autoboxing will *also* convert using `valueOf` (check in javap) and will have the same overhead.

Comment: Well obviously. But the compiler will only autobox the primitive when necessary. Hence we get the advantages of primitives when possible without any downside. If we do it the other way around we run into exactly the performance problems we see here. Prior to Autoboxxing using Long made sense - it helped avoiding the additional function calls, but today? Don't see any advantages.